# CF: Saving a Fusioncharts graph as an image to email it

Tags: coldfusion, fusioncharts

Does anyone have an example of this?  Google is not my friend tonight.    I have the newest version of FusionCharts.   I'm trying to figure out how to save a graph as an image file to email it.

I know how to save and then insert images into HTML emails, and I've done this before with other graph products.  I just cannot fine 1 good example of how to do this with Fusioncharts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in a template and point the imageSaveURL property at that template.

Your chart submits all necessary data for the chart to be reconstructed. In my example I'm serving it to the browser but you could save it locally and then attach to a `cfmail` if necessary.

I'm pretty sure I got this from the fusioncharts forums originally. This was updated for fusioncharts 3.1.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(Form, "width") >
    <cfset width = int(Form.width) />
<cfelse>
    <cfset width = int(Form.Meta_Width) />
</cfif>
<cfif structKeyExists(Form, "height") >
    <cfset height = int(Form.height) />
<cfelse>
    <cfset height = int(Form.Meta_Height) />
</cfif>

<cfif structKeyExists(Form, "data") >
    <cfset Form.data = Form.data />
<cfelse>
    <cfif structKeyExists(Form, "stream") >
        <cfset Form.data = Form.stream />
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<cfset user = viewState.getValue("user", structNew()) />


<!--- Impose some limits to mitigate DOS attacks --->
<cfif Not (0 lte width and width lte 5000)>
    <cfthrow message="Width out of range." />
</cfif>
<cfif Not (0 lte height and height lte 5000)>
    <cfthrow message="Height out of range." />
</cfif>


<!--- Check if we have the chart data --->
<cfif Not StructKeyExists(Form, "data") or Not Len(Trim( Form.data ))>
    <cfthrow message="Image Data not supplied." />
</cfif>


<!--- Default background color is white --->
<cfif Not StructKeyExists(Form, "bgcolor") or Not Len(Trim( Form.bgcolor ))>
    <cfset Form.bgcolor = "FFFFFF" />
</cfif>


<cfset gColor = CreateObject("java", "java.awt.Color") />
<cfset chart = CreateObject("java", "java.awt.image.BufferedImage") />
<cfset chart.init( JavaCast("int", width), JavaCast("int", height), chart.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) />
<cfset gr = chart.createGraphics() />
<cfset gr.setColor( gColor.decode("##" & Form.bgcolor) ) />
<cfset gr.fillRect(0, 0, JavaCast("int", width), JavaCast("int", height)) />

<!--- Get rows with pixels --->
<cfset rows = ListToArray(Form.data, ";") />

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(rows)#" index="i">

    <cfset pixels = ListToArray(rows[i], ",") />
    <!--- Horizontal index (x scale) --->
    <cfset horizIndex = 0 />

    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(pixels)#" index="j">

        <cfif ListLen(pixels[j], "_") eq 2>
            <!--- We have the color and the number of times it must be repeated --->
            <cfset color  = ListGetAt(pixels[j], 1, "_") />
            <cfset repeat = ListGetAt(pixels[j], 2, "_") />
        <cfelse>
            <!--- Background color; how many pixels to skip --->
            <cfset color  = "" />
            <cfset repeat = ListGetAt(pixels[j], 1, "_") />
        </cfif>

        <cfif Len(Trim(color))>

            <!---  If the hexadecimal code is less than 6 characters, prefix with 0 to get a 6 char color --->
            <cfif Len(Trim(color)) lt 6>
                <cfset color = RepeatString(0, 6 - Len(Trim(color))) & color />
            </cfif>

            <!--- Draw a horizontal line for the number of pixels we must repeat --->
            <cfset gr.setColor(gColor.decode("##" & color)) />
            <cfset gr.drawLine(JavaCast("int", horizIndex), JavaCast("int", i - 1), JavaCast("int", horizIndex + repeat -1), JavaCast("int", i - 1)) />
        </cfif>

        <cfset horizIndex = horizIndex + repeat />
    </cfloop>

</cfloop>

<!--- Get writer for Jpeg --->
<cfset writer = "" />
<cfset iter = CreateObject("java", "javax.imageio.ImageIO").getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg") />
<cfloop condition="iter.hasNext()">
    <cfset writer = iter.next() />
</cfloop>

<!--- Set Jpeg quality to maximum --->
<cfset jpgParams = CreateObject("java", "javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam").init( CreateObject("java", "java.util.Locale").init("en") ) />
<cfset jpgParams.setCompressionMode( jpgParams.MODE_EXPLICIT ) />
<cfset jpgParams.setCompressionQuality( 1 ) />

<!--- Write image to a memory stream --->
<cfset imageOutput = CreateObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init() />
<cfset writer.setOutput( CreateObject("java", "javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageOutputStream").init( imageOutput ) ) />
<cfset writer.write(JavaCast("null", 0), CreateObject("java", "javax.imageio.IIOImage").init(chart, JavaCast("null", 0), JavaCast("null", 0)), jpgParams) />

<!--- Stream the image to the browser (hint browser to display the Save dialog) --->
<cfset filename="whatever.jpg" />
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""#filename#""">
<cfcontent type="image/jpeg" variable="#imageOutput.toByteArray()#">
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have an example of what's calling this?   I'm not sure what "imageSaveURL" is except I assume it's a property of FusionCharts?  The only FusionCharts search results I'm getting in their documentation or knowledge base (or google) is a reference to exporting FusionMaps as images - but no example of what that property is.  Thanks!

Comment: PS how is a form involved in this (still massively lost here)?

Comment: Yes - imageSaveURL is a property of your chart. This should point to a web-accessible version of the code i posted - eg `imagesaveurl = 'fusionchartssave.cfm'` in your chart. The flash chart `posts` all the data via this url. I've just noticed you said you are using the newest version, maybe this approach has been deprecated. I used it with v3 charts

Comment: Got distracted on something else for a bit.   I have tried this now and there are no errors but nothing happens at all.  It looks like the file is suppose to open a browser prompt (and not save a file)?  I mean what I need is for the graph image to be saved in the CF temp directory so that I can insert it into an email (with a browser not being involved and this 'page' only being called on a schedule by the server).

Comment: I've been trying to read everything I can on this and it looks like (with CF only) it's not possible to do this without a browser window being involved so I guess there is absolutely no way for scheduler to call a page with fusioncharts graphs and have those graphs saved as temp files so that they can be emailed.   Ug.

Comment: Yes you are right - this is sent back to the server from a web browser. We are using highcharts instead of fusioncharts now and we use a command line tool called iecapt to render a webpage and then execute the necessary javascript. if you ask a new question i can give you more details on our approach

Answer (score 1):

Checkout out the latest blog post [Export Chart Images at Server Side](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/) where two options (wkhtmltoimage and PhantomJS. ) has been described with step-by-step instructions for both.

For ColdFusion, you can try the below code:

For example:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltoimage.exe" arguments="--javascript-delay 10000 http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/Code/MyFirstChart/ms-weekly-sales-no-animation.html savedimage.png" />
```

While executing the above script, we provide the following arguments:
    Call wkhtmltoimage
    Pass the URL of your webpage to it
    Pass the path and name of the image file (with extension) where the image will be saved
    If required, any additional delay to ensure the chart is completely rendered.