# Fusionchart not rendering on cfdocument

Tags: coldfusion, fusioncharts

I am using FusionChart in my projects and would like to use the charts in a `cfdocument` for creating a PDF. The chart is loading correctly in my ColdFusion page, but not within the PDF generated by cfdocument.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
        var myChart = new FusionCharts({
            "id" : "id", 
          "type": "column", 
          "width": "#chartwidth#",
          "height": "#chartheight#",
          "dataFormat": "xml",
          "dataSource": "#strXML#"
        }); 
      myChart.render("chartContainer");
    });
```

Comment: How do you embed the chart? Via HTTPS?

Comment: No, added the code on question

Comment: For future reference, the reason is the charts use javascript. cfdocument does *not* support javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Chart functions will not work inside `cfdocument`. So make the chart outside `cfdocument` and convert the chart to an image. Then display the image inside `cfdocument` like below and call the image path inside the `cfdocument`.

```
   <cfchart format="png" scalefrom="0" scaleto="1200000" name="chartimage">
       <cfchartseries type="bar" dataLabelStyle="value" 
           serieslabel="chart" seriescolor="blue">
             <cfchartdata item="January" value="503100">
             <cfchartdata item="February" value="720310">
             <cfchartdata item="March" value="688700">
             <cfchartdata item="April" value="986500">
             <cfchartdata item="May" value="1063911">
             <cfchartdata item="June" value="1125123">
       </cfchartseries>
   </cfchart>

   <cffile action="write"  
       file="#ExpandPath('charts/imageName.jpg')#"
       output="#chartimage#" />
```

Comment: How can I convert fusion chart into image it is not working inside cfimage, and cffile write

Comment: may be this reference will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036180/cf-saving-a-fusioncharts-graph-as-an-image-to-email-it

Comment: yes, I refereed this link, wkhtmltoimage/wkhtmltopd working fine.Thank you